# bulk loading HBase - NoClassDefFoundError(HBaseConfiguration)

Tags: java, maven, hadoop, mapreduce, hbase

My goal is to run a simple MapReduce job on a Cloudera cluster (CDH 5.9) that reads from a CSV file and  writes out in  HBase (bulk loading ).

I use SpringSource Tool Suite IDE.

I am getting below exception after executing this program.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/hbase/HBaseConfiguration
    at drivers.Driver.main(Driver.java:27)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseConfiguration
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 7 more
```

This is my driver code:

```
package drivers;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseConfiguration;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.KeyValue;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.ImmutableBytesWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.HFileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.LoadIncrementalHFiles;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.TextInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
import mappers.HBaseMapper;

// args[0] = inputPath
// args[1] = outputPath
// args[2] = tableName

public class Driver {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Path inputPath = new Path(args[0]);
    Path outputPath = new Path(args[1]);
    String tableName = args[2];

    Configuration conf = HBaseConfiguration.create();
    conf.set("hbase.table.name", tableName);

    Job job = new Job(conf, "NYCTaxi Bulk Import");
    job.setJarByClass(HBaseMapper.class);

    job.setMapperClass(HBaseMapper.class);
    job.setMapOutputKeyClass(ImmutableBytesWritable.class);
    job.setMapOutputValueClass(KeyValue.class);

    job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);

    HTable table = new HTable(conf, tableName);

    HFileOutputFormat.configureIncrementalLoad(job, table);

    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, inputPath);
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, outputPath);

    job.waitForCompletion(true);
  }
}
```

and This is my pom.xml file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>MapReduce</groupId>
  <artifactId>InsertHBase2</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <name>InsertHBase2</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.0-cdh5.9.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-yarn-common</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.0-cdh5.9.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-mapreduce-client-common</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.0-cdh5.9.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-mapreduce-client-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.0-cdh5.9.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
            <artifactId>hbase-server</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.0-cdh5.9.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
            <artifactId>hbase-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.0-cdh5.9.0</version>
        </dependency>   

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
            <artifactId>hbase-common</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.0-cdh5.9.0</version>
        </dependency>       
    </dependencies>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>cloudera</id>
            <url>https://repository.cloudera.com/artifactory/cloudera-repos/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
</project>
```

And when i checked the HBase jar in Maven dependency, I noticed that the HBaseConfiguration class exists.

[image]

and i already have the HBase jar in my Build path

[image]

Comment: please check my response

Comment: its there in the compile classpath doesn t  mean that it is also there in run  time classpath. how are you executing this any command or something else there you need to include this jar in to classpath

Comment: How i can put it in run time classpath?

Comment: is there any command you are using to run the application ? if yes you have to add it to the classpath. if you are usinng eclipse then you need to add it in run configurations.

Comment: i use this commande to run this application :
`sudo -u hdfs hadoop jar insertHBase-1.0.jar drivers.Driver /user/cloudera/trip_data* /user/cloudera/output-trip Fare`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133353/discussion-between-ram-ghadiyaram-and-abouyahya85).

Comment: export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=hadoop classpath:hbase classpath and your hadoop command mentioned above i.e sudo -u hdfs hadoop jar insertHBase-1.0.jar drivers.Driver /user/cloudera/trip_data* /user/cloudera/output-trip Fare
then it should work

Answer (score 1):

> #### General Note : NoClassDefFoundError In Java : NoClassDefFoundError is an error
>
> which is thrown when Java Runtime System tries to load the definition
>   of a class and class definition is no longer available. The required
>   class definition was present at compile time but it was missing at run
>   time.

The below dependency should have `HBaseConfiguration`

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
            <artifactId>hbase-common</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.0-cdh5.9.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

[image]

#### Cross check whether your are passing the same to your classpath or not.

in the below command all the jars related to hbase will come

```
export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=$HADOOP_CLASSPATH:`hbase classpath`
 echo $HADOOP_CLASSPATH // THIS IS TO ENSURE THAT YOU ARE NOT MISSING ANY HBASE JARS AGAIN
```

and then bundle this java in jar to run it within hadoop cluster like this:-

```
hadoop jar <jarfile> <mainclass>
```

Comment: check my updated answer above `hbase classpath` should have all hbase jars and you must add in the classpath like above.

Comment: if you are okay with the answer pls care to vote-up/accept as owner.